# VBS script (activating scrollock) at startup win 10

Tags: windows-10, script, group-policy

I created this script:

```
Set wshShell =CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wshshell.sendkeys "{SCROLLOCK}"
```

and put it into `C:\folder\a.VBS`.

It doesn't work if I add it (under Group Policy Editor) to `WINDOWS CONFIGURATION>WINDOWS SETTINGS>SCRIPTS (STARTUP/SHUTDOWN)>STARTUP`, while it does function if instead I put it in `USER CONFIGURATION>WINDOWS SETTINGS>SCRIPTS (LOGON/LOGOFF)>LOGON`.

The problem is that in this way it activates itself only after I've entered the password of my account and logged in (as, in fact, it should be), whereas I need it to run before that.

I'm under Windows 10 build 14393. I don't know if this information may be useful; my account is an Administrator account (the only one that I created on the PC), and my Users folder is located on another drive (D:/).

Comment: Why would you need Scrolllock of all things? Consider checking [this](http://www.askvg.com/force-capslock-numlock-and-scrolllock-keys-behavior-using-windows-registry/) out. My guess would be your approach is failing because it's not in a state where it can create a shell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need it because I have a Cooler Master Devastator II keyboard: it turns its backlight on when scroll lock it's pressed, which I have to do manually every time I start the PC. It would be useful if it did it automatically, particularly for my parents, who don't know almost nothing about computers and would find a bit difficult to identify the button to press (inserting the password without the light on is even more difficult because buttons are too  dark).

Comment: I've already tried the solution you referred to but unfortunately it doesn't work: I don't know why but regedit seems to accept only values 0 and 2.

Comment: If it is such a fancy keyboard it surely has its own drive/supplementary software, right? Did you check those settings? Oftentimes you might be able to find something there. Depending on your electric skills and toolset [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4n4oKf1ATo) might be a solution for you. Right now it doesn't seem like you will be able to have an easy fix. If it is about your parents maybe mark the key in some way using tape, a marker, a different key cap. Another option might be to use AutoIt and compile that into an exe file.